# How to disable right click on windows 8?

Tags: windows, embedded

I tried using the lockdown feature but apparently I cannot figure where to disable the right click action here. I also checked using the windows 8 embedded. I might be missing something. Can you give me an idea or answer how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-8/112099-disable-right-click-desktop.html running `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\
DWord - NoTrayContextMenu=1` should disable most functionality.